# Angular 2 and dynamic template ( remote content )

Tags: angular

I need to load dynamic template ( templates written by java backend ). So I tried 2 solutions 
1) componentfactory ( fe : https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d)
2) ng-dynamic module :  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic

The second is easier but the problem is that i can't get references of created components. What about such feature ?

Comment: Hi. Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here how I solved my problem :

In each component class, I put an injector that will be use on the `ngOnInit()`

```
constructor(private _inj: Injector){}
```

I get the reference of the parent component (component that uses dynamic component) and register the component (there is an array of child component in parent component)

```
ngOnInit() {

    let parentComponent = this._inj.get(ParentComponent);
    if (this.parentComponent) {
                this.parentComponent.registerChild(this);
    }
}
```